# Mysql DB Password field is filled by auto generated password, i cannot enter the words i wanted

Tags: php, mysql, database, passwords

I created a simple user login system with PHP.

[image]

On the signup page even though I wanted to enter the desired password, it is not saved in the database "password filed"

[image]

as an example, if I enter "testing" as a password, in the database password field it shows something like `@tyfyy$55rtg...blaa blaa blaa.` obviously an autogenerated PSW.
How to stop this?

Comment: This is called password hashing and is a security measure. You don't want to stop this. When you say "I created a simple user login system with PHP" - how did you create it?

Comment: Thanks, that word "hashing" itself is helpful